# rails 3 find a value in a params array

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, serialization, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery UI Sortable to sort some rows on my website.

Here is my view:

```
<section class="data-list">
    <article id="item_<%= item.id %>" class="data sortable">
        <!-- stuff goes here -->
    </article>
</section>
```

Here is my JS:

```
$('.data-list').sortable({items: '> .data'}).bind('sortupdate', function() {
    var release = getUrlVars()["id"];
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).sortable("serialize"),
        url: '/release_items/'+ release +'/prioritize'
    });
});
```

This creates a `params['item']` array that looks like this:

```
["1537", "1536", "1540", "1541", "1542", "1543", "1544", "1545", "1547", "1546"]
```

Here is my controller code:

```
def prioritize
    @release = Release.find(params[:id])
    item = @release.release_items
    item.each do |i|
        i.priority = params['item'].index(i.id.to_s).to_i + 1
        i.save
    end
end
```

My problem is that i have several `release_items` that are distinguished by an `item_type` column.  And as it stands now i currently don't have a good way in my controller to filter by item_type in my `@release = Release.find(params[:id])` line.

What i would like to do is make sure in the `item.each do |i|` loop that the priority is only set IF the item is in the `params['item']` array.  How would i do that?  Please let me know if this is not clear enough.  Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**

For every release, there are *n* number of release items.  THose release items are separated for display on the site by their `item_type` column (e.g., General, Project, Data, Patch).  So on the site there are 4 different lists of items and i want to be able to sort those 4 lists individually.  Like i stated above, the `params['item']` array being passed to the `prioritize` action in the controller has only the items that need to be sorted, which is want i want.

The problem i'm running in to is that the first two lines in the `prioritize` action will get all of the release items, not just the ones in the `params['item']` array.  The values in the array are the IDs of the release items that need to be sorted.  Instead of getting all release items, i want to only get the items that are in the `params['item']` array.  I do have a ReleaseItem model as well i can select from.  So, i'm trying to do this: (i know this isn't the correct code, just for clarity sake)

```
item = ReleaseItem.find(conditions: "id in params['item']")
```

Does that make a little more sense?  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to do...

```
def prioritize
    @release = Release.find(params[:id])
    items = @release.release_items.where("id IN (?)", params['item'])
    items.each_with_index do |item, index|        
        item.priority = index + 1
        item.save
    end
end
```

Comment: I updated my answer to include the information from your update.